# Access to the ManyToMany parent object

Tags: python, django

I have these two classes :

```
class Part(models.Model):
    title     = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    content   = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Review(models.Model):
    title        = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    parts        = models.ManyToManyField(Part)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In the admin of Part, I want to show in `list_display` the Review title. I tried this :

```
class PartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display   = ("title", "get_review")

    def get_review(self, obj):
        return obj.review_set.title
    get_review.admin_order_field = "part__review_set__title"
    get_review.short_description = "Review title"

admin.site.register(Part, PartAdmin)
```

I thought I can access to the *parent* object through `review_set` but I got an AttributeError :

```
'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'title'
```

How can I access to the parent object to display it in `list_display`?

Comment: I think it should be defined as a foreign key, not a m2m.

Comment: The fact that it is a many-to-many relationship means that there can be several reviews associated with a part. That's why you cannot fetch the title for a single review. `review_set` gives you a manager object, not a singular review object.

Comment: Why a ForeignKey? A Review can have many parts!